# Set custom keybinding for specific Emacs mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Though I know how to set a global key-binding in Emacs, I find it hard to even Google out the code for a local (minor-mode specific) key-binding. For instance, I have this code in my `.emacs`:

```
;; PDFLaTeX from AucTeX
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-p")
        (lambda ()
          (interactive)
          (shell-command (concat "pdflatex " buffer-file-name))))
```

I don't want to set it globally. Is there a function like `local-set-key`?

Comment: More and more I find myself going to the Emacs Wiki for help: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyBindingDiscussion There it shows that you can add a key binding to a mode key map and also shows how to find that map.

Comment: Yepp... I saw that one already, but I get `Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-mode-map` all the time. Hmmm...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To bind a key in a mode, you need to wait for the mode to be loaded before defining the key. One could require the mode, or use `eval-after-load`

```
   (eval-after-load 'latex 
                    '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map [(tab)] 'outline-cycle))
```

Don't forget either `'`—`eval-after-load` is not a macro, so it needs them.

Comment: How do you determine the first argument to `eval-after-load` programmatically?

Comment: I think it's enough to provide any function which belongs to the mode – e.g. `'LaTeX-mode` instead of `'latex` would do just as well.

Comment: For me the variable is called latex-mode-map (all lower case). LaTeX-mode-map doesn't exist.

Comment: `[(tab)]` is old syntax for `(kbd "TAB")`

Comment: @LenarHoyt: actually, no: `[(tab)]` is the same as `[tab]` which is the key-sequence sent when you hit the `TAB` key in the GUI version of Emacs.  `(kbd "TAB")` OTOH is the same as `[?\t]` which is the key-sequence sent when you hit that same `TAB` key in a text terminal (which is also the same key-sequence sent when you hit `C-i`).  The two options are "unified" inside Emacs by `function-key-map` which remaps `[tab]` to `(kbd "TAB")` if there's no binding to `[tab]`.  So if you want your binding to work both in a GUI and in a tty, better use `(kbd "TAB")`.

Answer (score 53):

I use the following:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-0") #'run-latexmk)))
```

to have a bind defined for LaTeX mode alone.

Comment: The `#` was redundant with me.

Comment: I had to set `'latex-mode-hook` instead (no caps). I also found the `#` unnecessary.

Comment: On sharp quoting #' http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html

Answer (score 12):

You need to identify the key map for that mode (for example, `LaTeX-mode-map`) and use the function `define-key`. As an example, along with activating `outline-minor-mode` within LaTeX mode, I have:

```
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map [(tab)] 'outline-cycle))
```

In this case the major mode (LaTeX) holds the key binding, but there is also an `outline-minor-mode-map`.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other answers satisfied my needs. So this may help other people. I wanted `Tab` to jump to the beginning of the line if I'm in Evil's normal mode (basically this means everywhere in Emacs), but I instead wanted it to cycle between org item states if I am in an org-mode document.

One option was to mess around with separate bindings and constant binding-rebinding whenever I switched buffers (because evil allows only one binding per key in its normal state).

But a more efficient option was to make `Tab` run my own code which runs the required function based on which major mode the current buffer uses. So if I am in a org buffer, this code runs `org-cycle`, and otherwise it runs `evil-first-non-blank` (go to the first non-whitespace character on the line).

The technique I used here can also be used by calling your custom function via `global-set-key` instead, for people who use regular non-evil Emacs.

For those who don't know Emacs lisp, the first line after the "if" statement is the true-action, and the line after that is the false-action. So if `major-mode` equals `org-mode`, we run `org-cycle`, otherwise we run `evil-first-non-blank` in all other modes:

```lisp
  (defun my/tab-jump-or-org-cycle ()
    "jumps to beginning of line in all modes except org mode, where it cycles"
    (interactive)
    (if (equal major-mode 'org-mode)
        (org-cycle)
      (evil-first-non-blank))
    )
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<tab>") 'my/tab-jump-or-org-cycle)
```